# Wikipedia-Like Search Box for SE in google search results

Tags: discussion, google

[image]

Can we ask google to add a search box like this for SO (or all of SE)

Comment: Sure, we *can ask*. But there is no garante about the answer...

Comment: @Traoth I guess thats all we can do about it, so Lets give it a go